# Split String by space with limited splitting C#

Tags: c#, regex, split

**Example Inputs**

```
1   0.000000 10.19.20.105 -> 74.125.236.200 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) request  id=0x000a, seq=51187/62407, ttl=128
6   0.097977 74.125.236.194 -> 10.19.20.105 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x000b, seq=62844/31989, ttl=57 (request in 2)
7   0.131456 74.125.236.198 -> 10.19.20.105 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x000b, seq=62845/32245, ttl=57 (request in 3)
8   0.143539 74.125.236.196 -> 10.19.20.105 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x000b, seq=62847/32757, ttl=57 (request in 5)
9   0.160567 74.125.236.192 -> 10.19.20.105 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x000b, seq=62846/32501, ttl=57 (request in 4)
10   0.177972 10.19.20.172 -> 10.19.20.255 NBNS 92 Name query NB INDERPAL-PC<1c>
11   0.270418 10.19.20.105 -> 74.125.236.194 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) request  id=0x000b, seq=62848/33013, ttl=128
12   0.318404 10.19.20.105 -> 74.125.236.194 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) request  id=0x000b, seq=62849/33269, ttl=128
13   0.330236 74.125.236.194 -> 10.19.20.105 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x000b, seq=62848/33013, ttl=57 (request in 11)
14   0.376039 74.125.236.194 -> 10.19.20.105 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x000b, seq=62849/33269, ttl=57 (request in 12)
17   0.397384 10.19.20.105 -> 74.125.236.195 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) request  id=0x000b, seq=62852/34037, ttl=128
18   0.438108 74.125.236.200 -> 10.19.20.105 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x000b, seq=62850/33525, ttl=57 (request in 15)
19   0.444489 10.19.20.105 -> 74.125.236.196 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) request  id=0x000b, seq=62853/34293, ttl=128
21   0.463515 74.125.236.195 -> 10.19.20.105 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x000b, seq=62852/34037, ttl=57 (request in 17)
22   0.475425 10.19.20.105 -> 74.125.236.197 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) request  id=0x000b, seq=62854/34549, ttl=128
25   0.522472 74.125.236.197 -> 10.19.20.105 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x000b, seq=62854/34549, ttl=57 (request in 22)
26   0.535794 Giga-Byt_5d:06:ac -> Broadcast    ARP 60 Who has 10.19.20.74?  Tell 10.19.20.94
27   0.537735 Giga-Byt_a0:ad:23 -> Broadcast    ARP 60 Who has 10.19.20.94?  Tell 10.19.20.74
28   0.550321 10.19.20.105 -> 74.125.200.95 TCP 55 58240â†’80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=16402 Len=1
29   0.574957 JetwayIn_a0:b1:a2 -> Broadcast    ARP 60 Who has 10.19.20.180?  Tell 10.19.20.172
30   0.584448 74.125.236.195 -> 10.19.20.105 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x000b, seq=62855/34805, ttl=57 (request in 24)


public class DataGridClass
    {
        public int SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public string DestinationIP { get; set; }
        public string SourceIP { get; set; }
        public string Protocol { get; set; }
        public int Length { get; set; }
        public string Info { get; set; }
    }
```

**Desired Output**

```
SerialNumber = 1
Time = "0.000000"
DestinationIP = "10.19.20.105"
SourceIP = "74.125.236.200"
Protocol = "ICMP"
Length = 74
Info = "Echo (ping) request  id=0x000a, seq=51187/62407, ttl=128"
```

I'm unable to split with white space as the string is inconsistent and secondly number of white space may increase or decrease

Thanks in advance

Update:

26, 27 are different from other's

Comment: You've only given us a single example - how are we meant to work out in what ways it can be inconsistent? It's easy to limit the number of splits performed, but we don't know what you mean about inconsistency...

Comment: use [`test.Split(new char [] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), assign the first 7 substrings (skipping the "->") into the class, put the remainder into the `Info`.

Comment: Unless you are practicing split/regex there is [Ping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class already.

Comment: /(\d+)\s+([\d\.]+)\s+([\d.]+)[\s->]+([\d\.]+)\s+([a-zA-Z]+)\s+([\d]+)\s+(.+)   - try this.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yeah I know about the Ping Class but how can I parse this data to that Class without loosing info?

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for the comment I have added few more examples

Comment: You can still parse with a single regex, you have to identify _ALL_ the different line formats and put them into an alternation. How is/should 26/27/29 be parsed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem if inconsistent white space, use:

```
var items = test.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Luckily, all of your data is in a consistent order and doesn't contain random spaces within the data.  So, given the items taken per the split above, you should find that the below always assigns correctly:

```
var dataGrid = new DataGridClass();

dataGrid.SerialNumber = int.Parse(items[0]);
dataGrid.Time = items[1];
dataGrid.SourceIP = items[2];
dataGrid.DestinationIP = items[4]; // Not a typo, we have to skip the ->
dataGrid.Protocol = items[5];
dataGrid.Length = int.Parse(items[6]);
datagrid.Info = string.Join(" ", items.Skip(7));
```

I tried to be clever with Info, but if it doesn't work like I think it would, feel free to simply say:

```
for (int i = 7; i < items.Length; ++i)
{
    dataGrid.Info += items[i] + " ";
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, i have updated the inputs for inconsistency data

Comment: Ah that's not so bad! Looks like they're always in the same order at least. I'll edit my answer when I get to the office :)

Comment: hi steve i think this will work however
is this the best way to do it
secondly getting an invalid argument error on this l;ine
`var items = test.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: yes this will work now but is this the best method or using regex is better
As I'm not good with regex?

Comment: I'm not great with Regex either.  I'd say with your current requirement, my solution will *possibly* be more performant and its easier to read.  As with all things code, I'd only switch to something I don't understand so well or that is less accessible when I encounter a problem (such as speed or incorrect parsing) of the current solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a regex. This seems to work for your data.
*Note - if Dot-net supports it, use horizontal tab `\h+` in place of all the `\s+` below.*

```
 #  @"(?m)^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(.*)"

 (?m)
 ^ 
 ( \S+ )            # (1), Serial Number
 \s+ 
 ( \S+ )            # (2), Time
 \s+ 
 ( \S+ )            # (3), Destination IP
 \s+ 
 ( \S+ )            # (4), ->
 \s+ 
 ( \S+ )            # (5), Source IP
 \s+ 
 ( \S+ )            # (6), Protocol
 \s+ 
 ( \S+ )            # (7), Length
 \s+ 
 ( .* )             # (8), Info
```

Output Sample for lines 1, 26, 27

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 108 ) 
1   0.000000 10.19.20.105 -> 74.125.236.200 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) request  id=0x000a, seq=51187/62407, ttl=128  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 , len 1 ) 
1  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 4 , len 8 ) 
0.000000  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 13 , len 12 ) 
10.19.20.105  
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 26 , len 2 ) 
->  
 **  Grp 5 -  ( pos 29 , len 14 ) 
74.125.236.200  
 **  Grp 6 -  ( pos 44 , len 4 ) 
ICMP  
 **  Grp 7 -  ( pos 49 , len 2 ) 
74  
 **  Grp 8 -  ( pos 52 , len 56 ) 
Echo (ping) request  id=0x000a, seq=51187/62407, ttl=128  

--------------------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 1873 , len 93 ) 
26   0.535794 Giga-Byt_5d:06:ac -> Broadcast    ARP 60 Who has 10.19.20.74?  Tell 10.19.20.94  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 1873 , len 2 ) 
26  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 1878 , len 8 ) 
0.535794  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 1887 , len 17 ) 
Giga-Byt_5d:06:ac  
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 1905 , len 2 ) 
->  
 **  Grp 5 -  ( pos 1908 , len 9 ) 
Broadcast  
 **  Grp 6 -  ( pos 1921 , len 3 ) 
ARP  
 **  Grp 7 -  ( pos 1925 , len 2 ) 
60  
 **  Grp 8 -  ( pos 1928 , len 38 ) 
Who has 10.19.20.74?  Tell 10.19.20.94  

----------------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 1968 , len 93 ) 
27   0.537735 Giga-Byt_a0:ad:23 -> Broadcast    ARP 60 Who has 10.19.20.94?  Tell 10.19.20.74  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 1968 , len 2 ) 
27  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 1973 , len 8 ) 
0.537735  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 1982 , len 17 ) 
Giga-Byt_a0:ad:23  
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 2000 , len 2 ) 
->  
 **  Grp 5 -  ( pos 2003 , len 9 ) 
Broadcast  
 **  Grp 6 -  ( pos 2016 , len 3 ) 
ARP  
 **  Grp 7 -  ( pos 2020 , len 2 ) 
60  
 **  Grp 8 -  ( pos 2023 , len 38 ) 
Who has 10.19.20.94?  Tell 10.19.20.74
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(^\d*) SerialNumber = 1
(\s\d*[.]\d*\s) Time = "0.000000"

\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b - [0] - first IP, [1] - second IP 

DestinationIP = "10.19.20.105"
SourceIP = "74.125.236.200"

([A-Z]{2,}) Protocol = "ICMP"
(\s\d{1,}\s) Length = 74
((Echo).*) Info = "Echo (ping) request  id=0x000a, seq=51187/62407, ttl=128"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex as well

^(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*->\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\d+)(.*)$

start (serial number) one or more white space (time) one or more white space (destination IP) zero or more white space -> zero or more white space (source IP) one or more white space (protocol) one or more white space (length) one or more white space (info) end

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string []inputs = {@"1   0.000000 10.19.20.105 -> 74.125.236.200 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) request  id=0x000a, seq=51187/62407, ttl=128",
                            @"6   0.097977 74.125.236.194 -> 10.19.20.105 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x000b, seq=62844/31989, ttl=57 (request in 2)",
                            @"7   0.131456 74.125.236.198 -> 10.19.20.105 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x000b, seq=62845/32245, ttl=57 (request in 3)",
                            @"8   0.143539 74.125.236.196 -> 10.19.20.105 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x000b, seq=62847/32757, ttl=57 (request in 5)",
                            @"9   0.160567 74.125.236.192 -> 10.19.20.105 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x000b, seq=62846/32501, ttl=57 (request in 4)",
                            @"10   0.177972 10.19.20.172 -> 10.19.20.255 NBNS 92 Name query NB INDERPAL-PC<1c>",
                            @"11   0.270418 10.19.20.105 -> 74.125.236.194 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) request  id=0x000b, seq=62848/33013, ttl=128",
                            @"12   0.318404 10.19.20.105 -> 74.125.236.194 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) request  id=0x000b, seq=62849/33269, ttl=128",
                            @"13   0.330236 74.125.236.194 -> 10.19.20.105 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x000b, seq=62848/33013, ttl=57 (request in 11)",
                            @"14   0.376039 74.125.236.194 -> 10.19.20.105 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x000b, seq=62849/33269, ttl=57 (request in 12)",
                            @"17   0.397384 10.19.20.105 -> 74.125.236.195 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) request  id=0x000b, seq=62852/34037, ttl=128",
                            @"18   0.438108 74.125.236.200 -> 10.19.20.105 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x000b, seq=62850/33525, ttl=57 (request in 15)",
                            @"19   0.444489 10.19.20.105 -> 74.125.236.196 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) request  id=0x000b, seq=62853/34293, ttl=128",
                            @"21   0.463515 74.125.236.195 -> 10.19.20.105 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x000b, seq=62852/34037, ttl=57 (request in 17)",
                            @"22   0.475425 10.19.20.105 -> 74.125.236.197 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) request  id=0x000b, seq=62854/34549, ttl=128",
                            @"25   0.522472 74.125.236.197 -> 10.19.20.105 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x000b, seq=62854/34549, ttl=57 (request in 22)",
                            @"26   0.535794 Giga-Byt_5d:06:ac -> Broadcast    ARP 60 Who has 10.19.20.74?  Tell 10.19.20.94",
                            @"27   0.537735 Giga-Byt_a0:ad:23 -> Broadcast    ARP 60 Who has 10.19.20.94?  Tell 10.19.20.74",
                            @"28   0.550321 10.19.20.105 -> 74.125.200.95 TCP 55 58240â†’80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=16402 Len=1",
                            @"29   0.574957 JetwayIn_a0:b1:a2 -> Broadcast    ARP 60 Who has 10.19.20.180?  Tell 10.19.20.172",
                            @"30   0.584448 74.125.236.195 -> 10.19.20.105 ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x000b, seq=62855/34805, ttl=57 (request in 24)",
                        };

        List<DataGridClass> data = new List<DataGridClass>();
        Match match;
        foreach (var item in inputs)
        {
            match = Regex.Match(item, @"^(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*->\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\d+)(.*)$");
            if (match.Success )
            {
                data.Add(new DataGridClass { 
                    SerialNumber = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[1].Value),
                    Time = match.Groups[2].Value,
                    DestinationIP = match.Groups[3].Value,
                    SourceIP = match.Groups[4].Value,
                    Protocol = match.Groups[5].Value,
                    Length = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[6].Value),
                    Info = match.Groups[7].Value,
                });
            }
        }

        if (data.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("SN: {0}, T: {1}, DIP: {2}, SIP: {3}, P: {4}, L: {5}, I: {6}",
                    item.SerialNumber, item.Time, item.DestinationIP, item.SourceIP, item.Protocol, item.Length, item.Info));
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class DataGridClass
{
    public int SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string DestinationIP { get; set; }
    public string SourceIP { get; set; }
    public string Protocol { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
}
```